# Connection to db on plesk230 from the domain

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to connect to the db that i created on the controler panel, 
from Visual Studio. It does connect to this db and change tables as needed,
but from the server it's failing with the error of connection isn't valid or open.

How to fix this problem? I tried many ways of [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)
and I also tried [this](https://my.hostmantis.com/knowledgebase/138/What-to-use-for-MSSQL-database-connection-string.html). Most of them work from local but not on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you're having is in Visual Studio (and not the production environment), it's possible that the DB is not Exposed (~Accessible, "Nagish") from outside. 
It's not an uncommon scenario to hide the DB and control all access to it - usually for security reasons.

If that's the case, I'm guessing you'll have to do with whatever tools you get from Plesk.
There might be an option to create an exposed SQL database (and you'll get a different server for that DB, an **Exposed** one), but keep in mind that this might create a security issue.

Behatzlacha!

Comment: it isnt the case on visual studio the connection work perfect on the production environment that for me its live dns it doesnt work ! but thank you for trying helping me!